# SAS: Select rows where the ID is in another table

Tags: sas

I have two tables, that both have an ID column. I'd like to select the rows in the one table, that have an ID that is in the second table.

I R I would do this be saying tbl1[tbl$ID %in% tbl2$ID,], but I haven't found a way to translate this into SAS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE result AS
SELECT t2.*
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
;
QUIT;
```

Comment: I'll just note that it's probably more efficient to avoid a join as it's only be used for its side-effect of membership testing here, and not its main task. `select * from t2 where id in (select id from t1)` should allow the optimiser to more efficiently plan the query, and is (imho) more clear as to the intent of the query.

Answer (score 2):

This is an expansion on Hong Ooi's method with the corrections suggested by Jon Clements.  I have found using a data step to be quicker than using SQL.  And it gives you more options for outputting data.  For instance, this solution creates a table called "match_error" which holds all IDs in table1 that aren't in table2.

```
proc sort data=table1;
  by id;
run;

proc sort data=table2;
  by id;
run;

data result match_error;
  merge table1 (in=in_T1) table2 (in=in_T2 keep=id);
  by id;
  if in_T1 and in_T2 then output result;
  if in_T1 and not in_T2 then output match_error;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data out;
  merge table1 (in=t1) table2 (in=t2);
  by id;
  if t1 and not t2;
run;
```

Comment: This'll only work if both datasets are in `id` order (or have a suitable index) and does the opposite of what the OP wants... it excludes items from one set that *aren't* in the other... The OP also states that they want rows from one dataset, they may not want additional columns or values over-written from the merge.